# How Cisco Anyconnect VPN creates network interface on OSX?

Tags: macos, vpn, networkextension

Cisco AnyConnect establishes VPN connection with out adding interface to `SystemPrefernecs -> Network`, but while running `ifconfig` on terminal it shows `utun1` interface created by Cisco VPN.

Without using `SystemConfiguration` apis called `VPNConfiguration`,`VPNTunnel` or `NetworkExtension` api how it is able to make VPN connection on MAC OS? or is there any other way to make VPN connection without using  `VPNConfiguration,VPNTunnel/NetworkExtension` apis on Mac OS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cisco AnyConnect uses a Kernel Extension (CiscoVPN.kext) which as far as I can tell is most likely built using BSD sockets.

It may require privileged code (i.e. run as root or with a helper) but I don't see why you couldn't do the same to create a VPN.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @Gary M , But i couldn't see "CiscoVPN.kext" under /System/Library/Extensions. is this cisco vpn kernel extension having different name or will it be added to different directory?

Comment: You're welcome @iSpark. On my mac the kext definitely in /System/Library/Extensions but the client is an old version (3.1.14018, from 2016). Maybe on newer versions the kext is elsewhere or has been removed in favor of other methods. Either way it doesn't change the fact that you can create a VPN using sockets.